# Non-Javascript Non-server-side method to assign href values from a variable?

Tags: html, css

This is something I feel is simple, but I can't for the life of me find any answer on.

The CONSIDERATIONS:

I am working on a site with some specific limitations server side so I can not do this with php or python or any other server side scripting.

I also hesitate to us JS or JQuery because occasionally people will disable JS which in this case would make the site completely unusable.

The ISSUE:

I want to pass a variable from somewhere static and easily editable to the href calls for my navigation buttons. I want to do this because how I have my site coded it has a nav for mobile and a nav for desktop that hide when in the non-relevant format. And I have a sitemap in the footer with links to the pages.  So on each page I have links to the pages in 3 locations on every page of the website, and if/when I need to edit or update something, I want to avoid the tedium of pasting 20 links 10 times in 3 locations on each page.

my Thinking and attempts:

I know that there are some obvious solutions that normally would be my go to, like using php snippet headers/footers and/or php variables. But this is not an option because of the platform I am building in. I also could obviously use JS to find and replace based on a class or id, but as I said above, if anyone disables JS then the site is unusable, and this is for a client that would probably want their customers utilizing the site.

What in my mind seems like it should work in some way is passing a CSS variable to the href attribute, but I can not find any documentation on a way to do this except for some vague reference to being able to use something like the following:
`<a href='' class='my-link'></a>`
where my-link is a defined variable. When I tried this, it just makes all links reload the current page.

Is there any way to do this using just HTML/CSS? Any little tricks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_site_generator

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.